# Save Dictionary of custom objects in Swift using UserDefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

I'm writing an app to work with contacts and trying to save information with UserDefaults but I'm getting SIGABRT. Here's my code, what I'm doing wrong?

```
class Contact{
var name = String()
var phone = String()

init(name: String, phone: String){
    self.name=name
    self.phone=phone
}
required init(coder decoder: NSCoder){
    self.name = (decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String)!
    self.phone = (decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "phone") as? String)!
}
func encode(with coder: NSCoder){
    coder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
    coder.encode(phone, forKey: "phone")
}
}
```

Creating contact in ViewDidLoad just for test:

```
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
var contactDictionary = Dictionary<String, [Contact]>()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    contactDictionary["A"] = [Contact(name: "Annabel",phone: "000")]

    let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: contactDictionary)
    userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "contactDictionary")
    userDefaults.synchronize()
    if let data = userDefaults.data(forKey: "contactDictionary"){
        print("yep")
        contactDictionary = (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [String : [Contact]])!
    }
    else{
        print("nope")
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make your class `NSCoding` compliant and inherit from `NSObject`. Change your Contact declaration to `class Contact: NSObject, NSCoding {`. And Btw conditionally cast to force unwrap it later is pointless. `decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String`

Comment: Regarding the force unwrap, the same applies here `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! [String : [Contact]]`

Comment: Not helping, getting the same SIGABRT, and it's writing: Unrecognized selector -[Contacts.Contact replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]

Comment: I have tested it here and it works. Edit your question and add your actual code

Comment: Thank u, I'll try to figure it out

Comment: check my answer posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your class NSCoding compliant and inherit from NSObject. Change your Contact declaration to class Contact: NSObject, NSCoding {. And Btw conditionally cast to force unwrap it later is pointless. `decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String`

```
class Contact: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var name = String()
    var phone = String()
    init(name: String, phone: String){
        self.name=name
        self.phone=phone
    }
    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder){
        self.name = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
        self.phone = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "phone") as! String
    }
    func encode(with coder: NSCoder){
        coder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        coder.encode(phone, forKey: "phone")
    }
}
```

---

Testing:

```
let contactDictionary = ["A":[Contact(name: "Annabel",phone: "000")]]

let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: contactDictionary)
UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "contactDictionary")

if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "contactDictionary") {
    print("yep")
    let contactDictionary2 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! [String : [Contact]]
}
else{
    print("nope")
}
```